Nuxt3 server-side console.log entry not outputting to std output
In my Nuxt3 application I have the following file defined in my /server folder structure:
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  ...doing something that makes the world a better place for my client
  console.log(`we're doing something great for you...`);
  ...do some more great stuff
})

When I run the application in local debug, I see the console.log output in the terminal.
When I build the app into a docker image, and run the container locally in Docker, I see the console.log output using docker logs....
When I deploy the app via Github Actions to our dev server (also built into a docker image and launched as a docker container), then the console.log entry DOES NOT appear in the logs.
Why is that?  What am I missing?  I thought it might have to do with something about a production build, but then, the docker image that I build and run on the developer machine is also the output of a production build.

/server is a server directory, hence is no reason to see a console.log in the browser devtools because it's not going to the client-side. Makes sense so far. Do you really need a log on the client-side from your server? Not sure if this might be feasible.

I'm not referring to the browser console.  The log entries I'm seeing above are on the server, not the browser.
